What does this error from npm-check-updates mean?
I just tried to create a new project using Vue 3, Vuetify 3, Vue-router and Pinia. I went to my c:\Vue directory, where all my source code goes, and executed npm create vuetify. This was the result:
Vuetify.js - Material Component Framework for Vue

√ Project name: ... vuetify-expense-tracker
√ Which preset would you like to install? » Essentials (Vuetify, VueRouter, Pinia)
√ Use TypeScript? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to install dependencies with yarn, npm, pnpm, or bun? » npm

◌ Generating scaffold...
◌ Installing dependencies with npm...


added 177 packages, and audited 178 packages in 3m

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

vuetify-expense-tracker has been generated at C:\Vue\vuetify-expense-tracker

Discord community: https://community.vuetifyjs.com
Github: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify
Support Vuetify: https://github.com/sponsors/johnleider

In other words, everything was fine to that point. I opened VSCode on the c:\vue\vuetify-expense-tracker folder and opened a terminal in that directory. I executed npm-check-updates and got this:
PS C:\Vue\vuetify-expense-tracker> npm-check-updates
Checking C:\Vue\vuetify-expense-tracker\package.json
[====================] 14/14 100%

 @mdi/font             7.0.96  →   7.4.47
 @vitejs/plugin-vue    ^4.0.0  →   ^5.0.4
 core-js              ^3.29.0  →  ^3.37.1
 eslint               ^8.37.0  →   ^9.3.0
 eslint-plugin-vue     ^9.3.0  →  ^9.26.0
 pinia                 ^2.0.0  →   ^2.1.7
 sass                 ^1.60.0  →  ^1.77.2
 vite                  ^4.2.0  →  ^5.2.11
 vite-plugin-vuetify   ^1.0.0  →   ^2.0.3
 vue                   ^3.2.0  →  ^3.4.27
 vue-router            ^4.0.0  →   ^4.3.2
 vuetify               ^3.0.0  →   ^3.6.7

Run ncu -u to upgrade package.json

I didn't see anything that looked like an error message so I proceeded to execute ncu -u and got this mess:
PS C:\Vue\vuetify-expense-tracker> ncu -u
Upgrading C:\Vue\vuetify-expense-tracker\package.json
[====================] 14/14 100%

 @mdi/font             7.0.96  →   7.4.47
 @vitejs/plugin-vue    ^4.0.0  →   ^5.0.4
 core-js              ^3.29.0  →  ^3.37.1
 eslint               ^8.37.0  →   ^9.3.0
 eslint-plugin-vue     ^9.3.0  →  ^9.26.0
 pinia                 ^2.0.0  →   ^2.1.7
 sass                 ^1.60.0  →  ^1.77.2
 unplugin-fonts        ^1.0.3  →   ^1.1.1
 vite                  ^4.2.0  →  ^5.2.11
 vite-plugin-vuetify   ^1.0.0  →   ^2.0.3
 vue                   ^3.2.0  →  ^3.4.27
 vue-router            ^4.0.0  →   ^4.3.2
 vuetify               ^3.0.0  →   ^3.6.7

Run npm install to install new versions.
PS C:\Vue\vuetify-expense-tracker> npm i
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: vuetify-expense-tracker@0.0.0
npm error Found: @vitejs/plugin-vue@4.6.2
npm error node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm error   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^5.0.4" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^5.0.4" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: vite@5.2.11
npm error node_modules/vite
npm error   peer vite@"^5.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@5.0.4
npm error   node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm error     dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^5.0.4" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Reinh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-22T15_49_30_507Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Reinh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-22T15_49_30_507Z-debug-0.log

What exactly went wrong here and what do I do about it? Vite had the most substantial upgrades. Was it a mistake to upgrade vite that much in a single jump? Should I have upgraded in stages?
What's the right way to deal with this? Using either --force or --legacy-peer-deps sounds like it would be a bad idea. My app seems broken before I've even started coding and I really don't know what to do.

I don't pretend to fully understand the npm-check-updates command and its various parameters but I found that this answer to an earlier question gave me a good result:
npm-check-updates (npm ncu): avoid breaking updates
Specifically, doing only the minor updates via ncu -t minor -u (as described in the first answer) gave me a clean app with no errors that I can now proceed to develop.
I don't know yet if failing to do the major updates is going to bite me further down the road but this solved my immediate problem.
